# tableView Lag when using cells with variable size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

There are multiple tableviews in my app, but the tableview with fixed cell size have no problem. However, 2 tableviews that I am using have variable cell size and it is causing lag/stuttering(when the cells with greater height value appears). I initially thought thats maybe because my cell is designed very inefficiently. However even simple table view cells with just a textfield(variable height) and a label(fixed height) is causing stuttering.

Layout constraints of the cell:
1. Label is given a height of 20, pinned 0 from the bottom with 5px trailing and leading
2. TextView is pinned 0 from top and 0 to the label below it with 5px trailing and leading

I have tried everything and looked at many articles but I am not able to find any helpful solution. Here is the cell file:

```
 import UIKit
  class ConvoCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var messageView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var BgViewRightContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var BgViewLeftContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var TimingInfo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

func datainit(message: String, time: String, type: Int32){
    self.messageView.text = message
    self.TimingInfo.text = time
    if (type == 1){
        bgView.backgroundColor = .orange
        self.messageView.textColor = .white
        BgViewRightContraint.constant = 5
        BgViewLeftContraint.constant = 50
        TimingInfo.textColor = .white
    } else {
        bgView.backgroundColor =  .white
        self.messageView.textColor = .black
        self.TimingInfo.textColor = .black
        BgViewRightContraint.constant = 50
        BgViewLeftContraint.constant = 5
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code for my cellForRowAt:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->    UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageBubble") as?   ConvoCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
     }
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    messagetable.separatorStyle = .none
    var currentMessage: Message!
    currentMessage = chat.fetchedMessages[indexPath.row]
    cell.datainit(message: currentMessage.body!, time: currentMessage.timingInfo!, type: currentMessage.type)
    return cell
}
```

In viewdidLoad(), i have added the estimated rowHeight and the automatic dimensions as well:
messagetable.estimatedRowHeight = 185
messagetable.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

Comment: Just some thoughts: are you doing non-UI work on a background thread but not switching back to the Main thread? Are you retrieving data (possibly images) from a cache for the cells but not switching back to the Main thread for setting them? What you have looks fine. I'd change `datainit()` to `update()` only because you're not initializing data there; you're updating an existing cell with the correct data, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Can you upload a video showing what are you seeing?

Comment: no there is absolutely no images being loaded. I initially thought it might be cause of image, but then for testing purposes, I removed those cells. Anyway, in this tableview, there are no images at all. The cells are very simple with just a text view and a label. Also, the data is just being read from an array of structure. I am not doing any background work. I am fetching data, appending it to the array and reloading the table. For testing purposes, I only tried just fetching from the normal DB and not doing anything in the background, but the problem still persists.

Comment: How do I upload a video here? Also, I am using firebase. I am observing the database. If any new child is added(in firebase), I am appending it to the array and the reloading the data. But this stuttering occurs even when the tableview doesn't have to reload and even when the device is offline(not observing the firebase DB).